# Mute microphone in speakers but still be able to analyze (createAnalyser) with Web Audio Api?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, microphone, analyzer, mute

Im trying to create an Analyser node to get the signal from a microphone, and be able to create a graphic with the received input. But I dont want to the speakers to still recive the microphone signal.

**Source (*microphone*) -> Analyser -> Destination(*?*)**

The destination is always the speakers... Can I put the destination to a void or similar, and be able to still analyze the microphone?

I tried to play with the Volumne (gain node) but that affects the analyser in the end.

In summary: I need to be able to analyze an input from the microphone but mute that signal on the speakers.

EDIT: Here is what I'm doing.

```
analyser = context.createAnalyser();
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.4;
analyser.fftSize = 64;

microphone.connect(analyser)
analyser.connect(context.destination);
```

This is working fine... but Im getting the sound on the speakers.
If I ask for example:

```
var data = new Uint8Array(analyzer.frequencyBinCount);
analyzer.getByteFrequencyData(data)
```

Then data will contain the reponse from microphone.

But if I add gain  after like this

```
volume.gain.value = 0; 
microphone.connect(analyser)
analyser.connect(volume);
volume.connect(context.destination);
```

or I do not make the connect to *context.destination*, then the data array will be all 0 (not reponse from microphone)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you don't even need to connect the analyser.  It should process without being connected to the destination.

Comment: I did that as well, and the analyser get reponse an array of 0 as well.

Comment: Would you mind checking out my similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799590/audiocontext-gain-node-does-not-mute-audio-source-web-audio-api

Comment: Hi, thanks, I remove ```audioGain.connect(audioContext.destination);  ``` and problem was solved

Answer (score 2):

Add a gain node after the analyser node and set its value to 0. So..

```
var volume = context.createGain();
volume.gain.value = 0;

microphone.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(volume);
volume.connect(context.destination);
```

Comment: That was the first thing that I did, but I get a array of 0 from the analyser

Comment: Would you mind checking out my similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799590/audiocontext-gain-node-does-not-mute-audio-source-web-audio-api